# need me use aggregation mongodb in arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**I need help in aggregate this query, I need aggregate values of debito**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a088f6584ccb0a665900726"),
"usuario" : "tamura",
"creditos" : [
    {
        "nome_do_credito" : "credito inicial",
        "credito" : 0
    }
],
"debitos" : [
    {
        "nome_do_debito" : "debito inicial",
        "debito" : 0
    },
    {
        "nome_do_debito" : "Faculdade",
        "debito" : "150.00"
    }
]
```

}

> I need the output

debito : 150

(0+150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to turn all your `debito` fields into a numerical type (as in `150.00`) since you cannot do Maths on strings (as in `"150.00"`). And then the following query should do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "debitos": {
            $sum: "$debitos.debito"
        }
    }
})
```

In case you have more than one document in your collection and you want the total sum over all documents you can run this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$debitos" // flatten the "debitos" array
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": null, // do not really group, just throw all documents in the same group
        "debitos": {
            $sum: "$debitos.debito" // sum up all debito fields
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thank u, I forget parseInt in my nodejs mongodb hehe